# Simple way to sum equal index of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
#'df1'
  a  
a .3
b .7

#'df2'

  b
a .7
c .2
```

How can I sum the equal column and index (a) from df1 and df2 and create a second dataframe like this one?

```
  b
a 1
b.7
c .2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution :

```
pd.concat((df1,df2),axis=1).sum(axis=1)
Out[125]: 
a    1.0
b    0.7
c    0.2
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

After `rename` using `add`

```
df1.rename(columns={'a':'b'}).add(df2,fill_value=0)
Out[410]: 
     b
a  1.0
b  0.7
c  0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [series.add](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html)

```
df1['a'].add(df2['b'], fill_value = 0)


a    1.0
b    0.7
c    0.2
```